# Balance doesn't show up after import in multibit

Tags: wallet, multibit

- I'm trying to import a private key that I exported from Blockchain, I import it, the right public key is created, but no transactions show up or balance?
  I've imported a bunch of private keys. and this is the first time I've run into something like this.
  Could it be the date? The key is exported in the right Bitcoin-QT format. What could it be?
- How can I enable 0 confirmation spending? I want to use it between addresses that I use so I don't need to worry about double spending; I really don't want to alter the source code and all that.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Multibit and on what platform ie OS?

There were issues with importing Blockchain wallets (a Reddit or BCT thread detailed lost BTC from a supposed lost imported Blockchain private key) so I believe recent Multibit versions have had Blockchain wallet imports disabled.

A couple threads to check:

- http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1rop3t/bitcoins_showing_up_on_blockchain_but_not_in/
- http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/26fymy/multibit_has_removed_imports_from_blockchaininfo/

There's nothing stopping you from using Blockchain's *export unencrypted keys* in either *base58* or *Bitcoin-QT* formats and pasting the private keys for import (PRIVKEY will either be 5H,5J,5K or K,L)